# Can sys.database_permissions contain REVOKE?

Tags: sql-server, permissions, metadata

The Microsoft documentation for [sys.database_permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-database-permissions-transact-sql) mentions that the valid values for `state` are "D", "R", "G", "W". The corresponding values for `state_desc` are "DENY", "REVOKE", "GRANT", "GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTIONS".

The value of "R" / "REVOKE" is a surprise to me. Isn't "REVOKE" just part of the syntax for eliminating a previously GRANT'ed or DENY'ed permission?

Is it possible for the values or "R" / "REVOKE" to be present in this system view? If so, under what circumstances would it appear?

I know that if you REVOKE a DENY'd permission, the DENY'd permission goes away; and if you REVOKE a GRANTed permission the GRANTed permission gets removed. Under what circumstance would SQL Server register the REVOKE'ing in `sys.database_permissions` instead of simply removing the existing GRANT/REVOKE/GRANT_WITH_GRANT_OPTIONS row?

Comment: The system does not support cross-site duplicates (for better or worse). This Q & A is on-topic and has value here, so we'll keep it as it is. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`REVOKE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/revoke-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) doesn't just remove access, rather it undoes a specific permission that was either explicitly given by a `GRANT` or `DENY`. In other words, if a permission is explicitly denied on an object for a **security principal** (e.g. **User**, **Login**, etc), that explicitly denied permission can be removed by using `REVOKE` on it.

After some research it looks like the use-case for "R" as a potential value of the `state` column in the `sys.database_permissions` view is for column level permissions that contradict the parent table's or view's permissions as per this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30358851) by [Mark Chesney](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4789684/mark-chesney):

> For objects which can have column permissions, such as tables or views, the presence of DENY or GRANT object permissions requires REVOKE for column permissions to be persisted.